# how can i fixed AJAX Error code 200 parseerror

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, jsp

```
function reviewOrder(no, order){
            $.ajax({
                url : 'reviewOrder.do',
                type : 'get',
                cache: false,
                data : { "no" : no, "order" : order },
                success : function(result){
                    console.log("ok : " + result);
                },
                error : function(request, error, XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, jqXHR, errorThrown) {
            console.log("code:"+request.status+"\n"+"message:"+request.responseText+"\n"+"error:"+error);
                }
            });
        }
```

could you help me with this please:
I am getting code 200 OK but ajax error is parsererror.

Comment: what does `result` have in it ? what does your server return back ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `JSON.parse(response);` in you success function. I have updated your code.

```
function reviewOrder(no, order){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'reviewOrder.do',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        data: { "no" : no, "order" : order },
        success: function(response){
            var result= JSON.parse(response);
            console.log("ok : " + result);
        },
        error : function(request, error, XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, jqXHR, errorThrown) {
            console.log("code:"+request.status+"\n"+"message:"+request.responseText+"\n"+"error:"+error);
        }
    });
}
```